# Proper way to check event delegates for nullity?

Tags: c#, events, delegates

Say I have a class that can fire some event like so

```
public SomeTypeOfEvent SomeEvent;
public delegate void SomeTypeOfEvent();
public void FooBar()
{
    if (SomeEvent != null)
        SomeEvent();
}
```

Is this the correct way to check to see if the `SomeEvent` delegate has any subscribers? I faintly remember being told a few times that this is not correct because between the checking of the delegate and its firing the subscriber(s) to the event could be removed.

*What is the proper/accepted way to check to see if a delegate is null?*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's perfectly fine way, if you are not bothering with more than one thread. If you are, then this is not thread safe, because in the middle of the `!=` check another thread may null the delegate value and you will get `NullReferenceException`.

In C# 6.0 the proper way is `SomeEvent?.Invoke()` using new null-conditional operator.

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986595.aspx) recommends it:

> Another use for the null-condition member access is invoking delegates
>   in a thread-safe way with much less code.

```
PropertyChanged?.Invoke(e)
```

In prior C# versions you can store the delegate value into the temporary variable, and it is the proper way to go.

```
var handler = this.PropertyChanged;
if (handler != null)
    handler(…)
```

Comment: Hmm looks like I need to get C#6, I really like that syntax a lot more than the later. Either way, thank you! This cleared it up for me!

Answer (score 0):

I usually do it this way (haven't used C# 6.0 much yet).

```
public event EventHandler SomeEvent;

private void OnSomeEvent() {
    var someEvent = SomeEvent;
    if (someEvent != null) {
        someEvent(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```